# How to convert string to JSON.parse in mongo compass or mongoshell

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection name Netflix which has a field name genres. I need to convert the genres string data type to JSON.parse in mongo compass.
[the data look like below here the field genres look like string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2D1I.png) 
but
[the data field genres must look like this after conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUT47.png)

I have tried
'''db.netflix.find({}).forEach(function(x) {x.genres=JSON.parse(x.genres); db.netflix.save(x);});'''
but it is throwing an error.
**ERROR:**
**TypeError**: db.asst.save is not a function